# Sort StatefulWidgets using its State

Tags: sorting, dart, flutter

I'm trying to use the following method to sort a list of `Widget`s.

```
class A extends StatefulWidget implements Comparable<A> {
  int x;

  @override
  int compareTo(A other) {
    return x.compareTo(other.x);
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AState();

}

class _AState extends State<A> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Async task to update x;
    Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 1), () {widget.x = 5;});
  }
}
```

But it gives a warning that `class A` is immutable and suggest to make `int x` to `final`.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: you should sort your data, not your widgets

Comment: @pskink: oh I forgot that.. Thank you..!! :D

Comment: sure, your welcome